# Restrict API calls. Allow only my mobile app

Tags: iphone, android, windows-phone-7, mobile

I want my **web server** to accept requests that **originate** only from my **mobile app**.

Since mobile apps are client apps that means that users can have the binary and decompile it or use a tool like Fiddler to interpret the API calls and reconstruct them (ex: in a console app).

So what I want is a way of **generating a key that is bound to my app and the user's device**.

The app is deployed in Windows Phone7, iPhone and Android. A cross platform solution would be ideal but something that works only in one platform is also more than acceptable.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that you are deploying an application to a client, the actual answer here is 'not possible'. You can make it difficult for someone to fake an 'official id', but because you do not have control over the system that is making the requests, it could be your application or anything else pretending to be your application.